# Auto select pre and next option for html select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have this select tag:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="stack">Stack</option>
    <option value="overflow" selected>Overflow</option>
    <option value="my">My</option>
    <option value="question">Question</option>
</select>
```

For example I selected the overflow option. How can I auto select the prev option and next option of my selected option, with jquery?? I don't have to use the namo or the value, just select the previos or next option, whatever it is.

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: The is a `selectone` kind of `select`. Therefore at any one time yo can only have one option selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the use case, but here are two functions that will do what you want:

```
function selectPrev() {
    // get the selected option
    var $selected = $("select[name=test]").find('option:selected');
    // remove the selected property
    $selected.prop("selected", false);
    // get previous option and add selected property
    var $prev_option = $selected.prev().prop("selected", true);
}

function selectNext() {
    // get the selected option
    var $selected = $("select[name=test]").find('option:selected');
    // remove the selected property
    $selected.prop("selected", false);
    // get next option and add selected property
    var $next_option = $selected.next().prop("selected", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, if you add multiple attribute to the `select`

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var i = $(this).find(":selected");
    var arr = $(this).children();
    i.next().prop('selected', true);
    i.prev().prop('selected', true);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx0acf40/)